# What does the following UNIX command mean?

Tags: shell, unix

What does the following highlighted UNIX command mean???

```
    grep -n "$string" $filename   
    if[$? -eq 0] #what does this command mean???
    then
    echo "string is match"
```

Comment: post the exact code you are using, don't put `**` all through it as stars mean something in shell script!

Comment: you may have an extra space

Comment: Can you double check what you are posting as I suspect you mean `$?` , rather than `$ ?`

Comment: `$?` is the exit code of the last command. Consult `man grep` to see what a return value of `0` from `grep` means.

Comment: @MattMcNabb can you tell me what $? means

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't try to make bold code (you can do it, but it is hard: **`if [ $? -eq 0 ]`** and indentation does not work properly.  Just put a comment after the line `if [ $? -eq 0 ]  # What does this line mean?`.  You should add the missing `fi` for completeness.

> `grep -n "$string" $filename`
>   **`if[$? -eq 0] # What does this command mean?`**
>   `then`
>           `echo "string is matched"`
>   `fi`

which is obtained by writing:

```
> `grep -n "$string" $filename`  
> **`if[$? -eq 0] # What does this command mean?`**  
> `then`  
> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;`echo "string is matched"`  
> `fi`
```

The `$?` is the exit status of the last command executed, which means `grep` in this context.  0 indicates success; any non-zero status indicates failure of some sort.  There isn't a standard for exit statuses in general.  POSIX does legislate the exit status for some commands.  For example, for [`grep`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html), it says:

- `0` — One or more lines were selected.
- `1` — No lines were selected.
- `>1` — An error occurred.

As written, your code fragment means 'execute a command `if[0` or `if[1` with two arguments, `-eq` and `0]`.  This is basically meaningless because there are unlikely to be commands with those names.

What is probably written uses spaces — spaces are critical in shell in general and the test command in particular:

```
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
```

This means 'test whether the value of `$?` is zero (which would mean that `grep` executed successfully).

However, it's not necessary to use the test command.  The script could be written:

```
if grep -n "$string" "$filename"
then
    echo "string is matched"
fi
```

And if you don't want to see the output from `grep`, just get the status, then use `grep -q` instead of `grep -n`.